# jQuery Text Crossfade

Tags: jquery

I'm aware of various *image* crossfade plugins, but i need to crossfade text. Like, I have text **A** within a , a  or a  element and I want it to fade away while, fading in, **B** takes its place.

Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quick demo [here](http://pastebin.me/4fbac3c48b580f0a83d78d28b81c990f).

```
 <html>    
   <head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
            $('#test').fadeOut(2000);
            $('#test1').fadeIn(2000);
      });
    </script>
    <style>
       h1 {font-size:12em;position:absolute; left:0;top:0}
       #test1 {display:none}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <h1 id="test">A</h1> 
       <h1 id="test1">B</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Wonderful service to asker, but not to SO. The link to quick demo should accompany the answer, not be the answer.

Comment: And you are who's judge and jury

Comment: @Basic, you could always edit the answer and help the community, guess you prefer to moan at others who help out more than yourself.

Comment: @redsquare Very true and a good point - I'll bear it in mind in future.

Comment: Link is dead. Smart thinking to include the code in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

VERY simple example

```
<div>
<div style="position:absolute;" id="div1">Hello</div>
<div style="position:absolute;" id="div2">World</div>
</div>

<script>
        $("#div2").hide( );
        $("#div2").fadeIn( 3000 );
        $("#div1").fadeOut( 3000 );
</script>
```

Comment: Just to make sure that the fadeIn/FadeOut happen in sequence you might want to do something along the lines of:
        $("#div2").fadeIn( 3000 );
        $("#div1").delay(3001).fadeOut( 3000 );

Comment: @Matt: In fact, `fadeIn` accepts a `callback` so you don't need to `delay`.